# Encrypt ApplicationServices ConnectionString

Tags: .net, security, web-config, asp.net-membership

Is there a way where I can set the .NET ApplicationServices connection string in the code behind? Instead of having plain text in my web.config? Or can I just put the encrypted value there and then decrypt and pass it again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encrypt settings in your config file. [Here is the article on MSDN on how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can [create/implement/use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfc2t3az.aspx) a [ProtectedConfigurationProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.protectedconfigurationprovider.aspx) to transparently decrypt the configuration settings.